# Cast uniqueidentifier to string and use in Where clause

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

figured out answer and edited question so it works now.

Here is my example

CustomerID column in my database is set to uniqueidentifier.

C#

```
string cid = ( This is a variable; it could be ANY guid the user chooses. )
```

Query String

```
                   " SELECT * FROM [db]
                    WHERE (CAST(CustomerID AS VARCHAR(100)) LIKE '%"+cid+@"%');"
```

The CustomerID field does not evaluate for a rows with the same cid. So the cid is having trouble being evaluated with the uniqueidentifier (CustomerID).

Comment: and what is your problem

Comment: is this a valid query?

Comment: Why do you need to cast at all? Just do `WHERE CustomerID = 'd7e9a6f1-c0f7-4c90-a2a0-016cde701408'`

Comment: because i need cid to be a variable. Will edit question to emphasize that

Comment: I'm giving you the raw SQL there, you can make the C# code yourself from that.

Comment: @JamesCoderBot That doesn't change anything. The query can still be `WHERE CustomerID = @cid`, assuming you're properly parameterising your query (which it looks like you are not)

Comment: So even though CustomerID is a uniqueidentifier. i can just do a where clause setting it equal to a string and it will evaluate properly? Because so far that doesnt work.

Comment: @DavidG well it doesnt work when i use a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't build your query by string concatenating user input into the query. It can lead to [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) which is a **serious** issue.

Instead you should use `parametrized queries`, where you pass the user input to the query in the form of a parameter. The underlying framework/driver/etc will then make sure that the user input is prepared in a way that cannot accidentally become sql code.

Something like this:

```
Guid cidAsGuid = new Guid(cid);
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [db] WHERE CustomerId = @customerID");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerID", cidAsGuid);
```

And then you can use the command to execute a reader or fill an adapter or some other thing you need to do.

This has the added benefit that an index on the `CustomerId` column can be used to speed up the query, whereas if you search by converting the `CustomerId` from a `Guid` to a `string` means the database will have to scan the whole table. For small tables you won't notice much difference but for large tables the difference will be significant.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `like` if `CustomerID` is `uniqueidentifier` too.

```
WHERE (CAST(CustomerID AS VARCHAR(36)) = @cid)
```

Comment: This does not work. Also cid is a c# variable string

Comment: You asked "is this a valid query", Yes this is valid query. And how you will use this query you didn't mention.

Comment: What format is "cid" in in your query? is it a string? is @cid SET/DECLARED at varchar36?

Comment: cid is parameter that mysql takes for query condition, it's varchar(36)

Comment: you cant just write cid in a query string like that

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a few possible issues;

- There's no condition defined for the ISNULL e.g. ISNULL(Column,valueifnull).
- Also the actual query must specify a column to use ISNULL in that structure.
- There's a missing "closing bracket" on the ISNULL.

Something such as this should work:

`SELECT ISNULL(
                (
                  SELECT Column1 FROM MyTable
                  WHERE (CAST(CustomerID AS VARCHAR(100)LIKE '%"+cid+@"%') 
                )
             ,'')`

Comment: You've broken the query even more now, the parens are a bit messed up. Also, please learn how to format your posts properly.

Comment: I fixed the isNull problem. But the unique identifier still isnt being evaluated properly.